# Assign a color for entire row in Listview VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I finally solved this problem. Since I didn't find any useable source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with two steps.

1. Filling listview with data
2. Then colourize the individual data, row by row.
   So here is the code which worked for me.

   ```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 'Filling with data
    lrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A99999").End(xlUp) + 1
    With ListView1
        .View = lvwReport
         .FullRowSelect = True
        .LabelEdit = lvwManual
        .Appearance = cc3D

   With .ColumnHeaders
   .Add , , "column1", 16
   .Add , , "column2", 50
   .Add , , "column3", 75
   .Add , , "column4", 75
   .Add , , "column5", 55
   .Add , , "column6", 60
   .Add , , "column7", 70
   .Add , , "column8", 70
   .Add , , "column9", 70
   .Add , , "column10", 70
   End With

   For i = 2 To lrow
   Set li = .ListItems.Add(, , Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Text)'this is the first column
    'these are the sub columns
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Text
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Text
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Text
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Text
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Text
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Text
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Text
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , Sheets(1).Cells(i, 9).Text
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , Sheets(1).Cells(i, 10).Text
   Next I
   End With
   ListView1_AfterUpdate
   End Sub

   Private Sub ListView1_AfterUpdate() 'the actual coloring
   Dim x, y, r, c As Integer
   r = ListView1.ListItems.Count
   c = ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Count - 1
   For y = 1 To c
   For x = 2 To r


        If Sheets(1).Cells(x, 20) <> "" Then 'condition for coloring
            ListView1.ListItems(x - 1).ListSubItems(y).ForeColor = RGB(150, 0, 30)
        Else
            ListView1.ListItems(x - 1).ListSubItems(y).ForeColor = vbBlack
        End If
        Next
   Next
   x = Empty 
   For x = 2 To r 'It is required since it distinguishes listitems and listsubitems.
        If Sheets(1).Cells(x, 20) <> "" Then
            ListView1.ListItems(x - 1).ForeColor = RGB(150, 0, 30)

        Else
            ListView1.ListItems(x - 1).ForeColor = vbBlack
        End If
        Next
   End Sub
   ```